# Can gnuplot be aware of which OS is the host, other than via environment variables?

Tags: operating-system, environment-variables, gnuplot

I need to develop a script in gnuplot that is usable under both Windows and Linux.

To decide which OS I have, I wrote

```
OS=system("echo %OS%")
print "OS = ", OS
if (OS eq "Windows_NT") \
  ...; \
else \
  ...;
```

and it worked.

**Is there an alternative way, native to gnuplot, which does not depend on environment variables?**

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use environment variables ? Because that's what they are for, aren't they ?

Comment: Because it depends on the variable `OS` (or the like) being set, and as far as I have observed, it is most often not default behaviour. Then, my script would not be very useful for distributing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use the internal variable `GPVAL_SYSNAME`:

```
gnuplot> print GPVAL_SYSNAME
Windows_NT-10.0
```

which is on Windows initialized in `eval.c` as:

```
ZeroMemory(&osvi, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO));
osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO);
GetVersionEx(&osvi);
snprintf(s, 30, "Windows_NT-%ld.%ld", osvi.dwMajorVersion, osvi.dwMinorVersion);
fill_gpval_string("GPVAL_SYSNAME", s);
```

In order to test if this string starts with "Windows", one could use the Gnuplot's internal `strstrt` function as:

```
if (strstrt(GPVAL_SYSNAME, "Windows") == 1) {
   ....
}
```

In addition, there is also `GPVAL_MACHINE`:

```
gnuplot> print GPVAL_MACHINE
x86_64
```

Comment: Hit the nail in the head!